# wordpress - загрузка изображений в виджетах

Tags: wordpress

Нужно сделать виджет из 6 картинок. К примеру есть стандартный виджет "Изображения(media_image)" в котором есть кнопка позволяющая выбрать медиа файлы, загруженные на сервер.

Как можно использовать стандартные функции wordpress для загрузки изображений? Может есть статьи или документация, хотелось бы узнать как это делается.

[image: вот что пример того что нужно]

[image: Загрузка изображений]